# Store the selected quantities and the price in an array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a congress details page that has a form so the user can select the quantities that he wants for each tiket type, the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('congresses.registration', ['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])}}">
    <ul>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <span>{{$type->name}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <select name="types[{{ $type->name }}]">
                        <option selected></option>
                        @for ($i = $type->minPerUser; $i <= $type-> maxPeruser; $i++)
                            <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                        @endfor
                    </select>
                    <span>X {{$type->price}}</span>
                </li>
            @endforeach
    </ul>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Next" />
    </div>
</form>
```

When "Next" button is clicked I want in the RegistrationController to store the selected quantities by the user and the price of each type in the storeQuantity() method so that is possible to send this info to the registration page. And also in this method redirect the user to the registration page.

I have the code below but Im not having success in the part of storing the selected quantities and the price in an array so that is possible to return that array with the necessary info to the registration view. Do you know how to do that?

```
public function storeQuantity(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
        ]);

        //dd($request->all());

        $typeQuantities = $request->get('types');
        foreach($typeQuantities as $typeName => $quantity){
            $type = TicketType::where('name', $typeName)->firstOrFail();
            $price = $type->price;
            //dd($price);    shows the price, example "10"
        }

        return view('congresses.registration')->with('selectedtypes', $selectedtypes);
    }
```

The "dd($request->all());" shows:

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => ""
  "types" => array:2 [▼
    "center bench" => "2"
    "lateral bench" => "1"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the foreach:

```
...
$price = $type->price;
$selectedtypes[$type->name]['qty'] = $quantity;
$selectedtypes[$type->name]['price'] = $price;
```